# Need to print out iPhone text messages

Tags: email, messages, printing, macos, text

I have a court case and have text messages on my iPhone I need to transfer to my iPad email for evidence.  Every time I try it doesn't work, it will send them to my iMessage but not my email.  I need to print them out How do I do this?

Comment: If you are heading to court, pay someone to do the analysis. Having the fox watch the hen house is a good way to raise more suspicion and you'll be best served by the evidence speaking for itself without your "assistance", however ethical and well intentioned it might be.

Comment: Connect your phone to the screen and display it directly

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I think I see what's happening:

**As it sounds like you may have already figured out, you can forward multiple texts by:**

1. Holding an individual text until the "copy/more" dialog pops up.
2. Picking "More"
3. Clicking the circle next to the left of each text you want to forward.
4. Clicking the "share" arrow on the lower right
5. Picking who you want to send them to

**But, there are two possible problems:**

- The "recipient" you're picking in step 5 above is the recipient for a
  text or iMessage; there's no way to select email instead.
- The forwarded texts lose the "speaker" indicator, so with multiple texts, it's a little hard to see who said what.

**If you only care about getting the messages into an email (and don't need the speaker) first issue, the easiest solution is this:**

1. Go to the text you forwarded yourself with all the texts lumped
   together (that you got by following the 5 steps above)
2. Hold your finger on it until "Copy/More" appears
3. Pick copy
4. Copy it into an email, and send it to yourself, print it, etc.

**If you need to print something that indicates who was speaking, your best bet may be this:**

1. Go to the beginning of the dialogue you want in your texts.
2. Hold the Home button, and press the power button without letting go of home.
3. You'll see a white flash, indicating that the hone took a screen capture.
4. If all the messages you needed didn't fit on one screen, scroll to the next set, and repeat.
5. Once you have done this for all the messages you need, go to the "Photos" app, and open "Camera Roll" - you'll see those screen captures as the most recent images.
6. Click "select" in the upper right corner, then select all the pics you need.
7. Hit the "share" button in the lower left corner, then pic "Mail"

That will let you email yourself (or anyone else) printable images of the text conversation.  Note that they'll be pics, so you can't edit the text, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There is an app called PhoneView that lets you view and print your messages as a PDF.
see it here http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/
P.S. I am not in any way affiliated with ecamm. :-)

Comment: Third party tools might be an issue because he needs it for a legal action. He should really be using a tool provided by Apple. (I'm in the same situation).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print out few text messages then you can take the screen shots and email the pictures to your computer for printing or simply AirPrint the screenshots. You might also consider third party apps like Phoneview or Tansee to print out your text messages. This guide worth a look: http://www.iphone-to-pc.com/how-transfer-messages-iphone-pc.html

Comment: Third party tools might be an issue because he needs it for a legal action. He should really be using a tool provided by Apple. (I'm in the same situation).

Comment: @JWW, AFAIK Apple does not offer any app/software to print iPhone text messages.

Comment: Taking a screenshot of your text messages and AirPrint is a really clever idea but the whole process can be very time consuming to capture a long text conversation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm one of the developers for Decipher TextMessage, [a program that will help you print your iPhone text messages](http://deciphertools.com). I've gotten feedback from many of our customers who use the software for that exact purpose, so I've spent some time adding features to help support using our printouts for court cases.

There's a plain-text printout export as well as a fancier export that you can use to print with the iPhone-like text bubbles and image previews. Everything includes the party names (from your phone contacts) as well as the phone number, so you should have all of the needed information on the printout.

I hope this helps! You can try a free trial of our program on our website: http://deciphertools.com

Answer (score 3):

Forwarding messages from the messages app only allows sharing by messages, as you have found out.  I would question how useful this is anyway, as it strips out any useful meta information, including who said what, and instead just lists all the content with no context.  A better method although perhaps a little more time consuming might be to take screenshots.

If you swipe left to reveal the time and datestamps, then hold home and press power you should take a screenshot.  Take enough to show all your messages that you are interested in, and you can then wither just sync your photos to your PC or Mac, or even get clever and stitch them together into a single large image.  Benefits of this are that it is clear the context that they are sent in, and also clear that rather than being just a text copy that could have been altered they are clearly shown to be unaltered.

Perhaps even better still because you clearly can edit images, is to use AirPlay mirroring to your Mac, and use Quicktime to record a video of the window as you slowly scroll down the list, occasionally left swiping to show timestamps.

Comment: I really like the AirPlay suggestion, but wonder if any court would entertain that sort of evidence. Unless the OP wants the record to keep their story straight when testifying and consulting with their lawyer, I'd say any efforts we can offer on securing advice would be well intentioned but likely not compliant with whatever court might be hearing this case.

Comment: Sure, we can't comment on what might or might not be admissible in any particular court, but for taking a copy you certainly, for your own sanity, need to maintain context and providence or the text could simply have been made up or amended by anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking strictly of your desire to send particular messages to your inbox, there is a way that works with at least AT&T (I have tested it only with AT&T) as a cellular provider. You need the ability to send MMS messages.

It is actually a simple process than:

1. Switch off iMessage on your phone.
2. Tap and hold on a message that you would like to forward.
3. Select "More".
4. Select the Messages you would like to send.

   - Note that these messages will be concatenated together.
5. Forward them to your email address.

They will arrive in your inbox from an email address like [your phone #]@mms.att.net.