# Apple tool to print SMS Messages

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, printing, sms

I need to print some SMS messages for a legal action. What tool does Apple provide to print SMS messages with their time stamps and other metadata?

This is similar to [Need to print out iPhone text messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116428/need-to-print-out-iphone-text-messages), but I don't need to transfer them to a different email account.

I don't want a third party tool or jail broken the device. A third party tool or jail broken device might not produce material that satisfies the ["best evidence"](http://www.justice.gov/criminal/cybercrime/docs/ssmanual2009.pdf) or ["accurate representation"](http://www.justice.gov/usao/eousa/foia_reading_room/usab5906.pdf) rules. If the evidence produced does not satisfy the rules, then it will likely waste time and money in the action.

Does Apple make such a tool for their devices?

Comment: I've edited out the discussion for [meta] whether this is a dupe or not and reopened it. I believe the correct answer is "No - Apple makes no tool to print SMS messages" and the larger answer is you will need to hire someone to do forensic evidence gathering and not prepare data DIY style for it to meet legal criteria for evidence. Perhaps you just want it for you and your lawyers to prepare for the case so we'll try to cover what's possible as opposed to what's legal.

Comment: Use SQLite to query the database `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db` on your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. Does that require a JB device? if so, that might be a problem.

Comment: No, it just requires you to either use [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) or to extract the database from a backup.

Comment: Thanks @bmike. If I use an Apple tool to print the messages and metadata, then the resulting evidence should be OK. The evidence would be gathered using the platform vendor's tools and satisfy the "best evidence" rule. If I jail break the device or use a third party tool, then I'm likely looking at $5000 to $15000 in legal fees to sort out the motions to have the evidence suppressed. Hence the reason I'd like to "do it right" the first time. If the community does not know, then I'll open an Apple support ticket or a radar (and report back what I discover).

Comment: Feel free to post a copy of the radar to http://openradar.appspot.com/ :-) Andrew's suggestion to use the bundled sqlite binary on OS X to read the contents of the `sms.db` might be one "Apple" provided tool chain to get you what you need. I use PhoneView instead of iFunBox to read files from stock iOS devices. Editing in the "best evidence" to your question might strengthen the question as well.